# Recovering Very Important Lost Data From external hard drive when copying it

Tags: external-hdd

I was trying to copy back up documents file on my external HD and something didn't work.  When I went back to the external hd to retry the copy, the file was gone.  How can I recover a file on an external hard drive that was deleted by accident?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `testdisk`

install

`sudo apt-get install testdisk`

attach external drive and run

`sudo testdisk`

select >[no log]

select external drive from options press >[proceed] >[intel]

and use >[analyze] >[quick search] >[deeper search]

it will analyze drive and give list of files **deleted files will be red**
you can then copy them to desired place.

Comment: @user56946 if is Correct then mark it as right answer.